# Mobile HTML rendering numbers

Tags: html, xhtml, mobile, mobile-website

I have a mobile WEB Page showing a bank statement. Something like this:

```
DATE          | DESCRIPTION              | AMOUNT
--------------|--------------------------|---------------
Jan 2nd 2010  | Clothes                  |  USD 1.839.000
Sep 23rd 2010 | Drinks                   |  USD 2.837.000
```

I am using `.` as a thousand separator since that's our locale configuration for that.

HTML is very simple. Something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>DATE</td>
      <td>Clothes</td>
      <td>AMOUNT</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jan 2nd 2010</td>
      <td>Clothes</td>
      <td>USD 1.839.000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Sep 23rd 2010</td>
      <td>Drinks</td>
      <td>USD 2.837.000</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The problem I am having is that iPhone's Safari, Android Browsers and some Nokia Browsers are *thinking* (erroneously) numbers such as `1.839.000` and `2.837.000` are *phone numbers* hence rendering them as links to make phone calls or do some texting.

My question: Is there a special TAG/ATTRIBUTE/CSSSTYLE to tell mobile browser to show that kind of text as **plain text**?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting question. Does adding span tags in between help?: `<span>2</span>.837<span>.000</span>`

Comment: @Pekka: let me try that. Thanks!

Comment: nice! But it's of course kind of a kludge. If you have no phone numbers on the entire page, Kenny's/Brian's suggestion may be better. Anyway, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know about Android or Nokia, but for iPhone you could use the [meta tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW2):

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

to disable detecting anything as a phone number.

Comment: Unbelievable, finally something that is NOT ignored by Opera Mobile Classic!! This really worked, I'm so moved I'm about to cry  :P

Comment: To keep the click2call but remove the blue underline effect:  a[href^=tel] { 
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you do it [for the iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/index.html#GENERAL-DISABLE_AUTOMATIC_DETECTION_OF_PHONE_NUMBERS_IN_WEBPAGES), which [seems to work](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/phone-numbers.html) for Android as well; it may work in other browsers, that's all I have to test with at the moment:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to keep the functionality that recognises the phone number as such and allows you to tap it, use this solution:

Since iOS adds a `<a href="tel123456789">` tag around the number, all you have to do is make a css rule that styles this tag:

`a[href^=tel] { color: inherit; }`

credit goes to [this Razor Edge Labs article](http://razoredgelabs.com/2013/03/how-to-stop-apple-ios-devices-from-styling-phone-numbers/).

Answer (score 1):

Longshot, but, try writing the period as `&#46;` - there are smart codes that can disable that for mobile safari, etc, but that only works for one-two devices.  If you're lucky, you'll bypass their regex.

Comment: Yeah, this (I'm out of votes for today) or maybe some weird unicode character that happens to look like a `.` as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, adding arbitrary spans seems to break detection for the browser in question:

```
<span>2</span>.837<span>.000</span>
```

however, an explicit solution in the form of a "don't parse this" attribute or Meta tag would of course be preferable, as it would be more certain to work in the future and for all/most platforms.