# How do I remove the blue styling of telephone numbers on iPhone/iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

Is there a way to remove the default blue hyperlink colour from a telephone number when viewed on an iPhone? Like a specific Mobile Safari tag or CSS to add?

I only have this in place for the number:

```
<p id="phone-text">Call us on <strong>+44 (0)20 7194 8000</strong></p>
```

And there are no hyperlinks but iPhone still renders this text number as a hyperlink.  I have this rendering issue on some of my websites but can't see why this is occurring.

I did read this post:

[Mobile HTML rendering numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712475/mobile-html-rendering-numbers)

But is that the only solution possible?

Comment: Not entirely sure whether this is the same thing, can you check please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712475/mobile-html-rendering-numbers

Comment: @Pekka: I think this question is similar but distinct. That was about preventing something from being wrongly interpreted as a phone number. This appears to be about preventing real phone numbers from uglying up your design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 459):

Two options…

## 1. Set the `format-detection` meta tag.

To remove all auto-formatting for telephone numbers, add this to the `head` of your `html` document:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

View more [Apple-Specific Meta Tag Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

> **Note:** If you have phone numbers on the page with these numbers you should manually format them as links:
>
> ```
> <a href="tel:+1-555-555-5555">1-555-555-5555</a>
> ```

---

## 2. Can’t set a meta tag? Want to use `css`?

Two `css` options:

---

### Option 1 (better for web pages)

Target links with `href` values starting with `tel` by using this css attribute selector:

```css
a[href^="tel"] {
  color: inherit; /* Inherit text color of parent element. */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline. */
  /* Additional css `propery: value;` pairs here */
}
```

---

### Option 2 (better for html email templates)

Alternatively, you can when you can’t set a meta tag—such as in html email—wrap phone numbers in link/anchor tags (`<a href=""></a>`) and then target their styles using css similar to the following and adjust the specific properties you need to reset:

```css
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
```

If you want to target specific links, use classes on your links and then update the css selector above to `a[x-apple-data-detectors].class-name`.

Comment: Hi Beausmith, thanks for your answer. Ended up using your first solution in the end a while ago...just wondered if there another solution to the problem.

Comment: @Beau Smith, that worked for me too, but not on iPod 1st Generation's Safari. Is there any specific tag for that old browser?

Comment: 45 answers and still haven't made that the solution? :)

Comment: This is the answer. Had a contact page that the numbers wouldn't show up on iPads and iPhones. This did the trick, thank you!

Comment: RE using 'tel:' links to markup phone numbers: it has also been suggested to use microformats as an alternative (http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/21121/36009).

Comment: The CSS from answer is not functioning anymore. Use @Silverback's answer!

Comment: If you are using WordPress you can also use our plugin to add the meta tag - https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-browser-telephone-format-detection/

Comment: This is happening to me on icons I have. The icons are black on the web and Safari and chrome, but on mobile devices Safari it always comes up as blue. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wayne - This might simply be the psudo-style of `:visited` links. If something else, you need to provide more info about the icons to get help. Depending upon what type of icons (img, svg, glyphs, etc), some property is being changed on mobile (likely `color` or `background-color`). Since `background-color` is not included here, try adding `background-color: inherit !important;`.

Comment: it is a react-icon from the react-icons npm library. Which is an svg I believe

Comment: Whenever someone needs to remove underline in Chrome on iPhone, use

`chrome_annotation {
  border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
}`

Answer (score 172):

Just to elaborate on an earlier suggestion by David Thomas:

```
a[href^="tel"]{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Adding this to your css leaves the functionality of the phone number but strips the underline and matches the color you were using originally.

Comment: This is the best solution BUT it should be like this I believe: 
a[href^="tel"]{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}
At least that's what worked for me. You need the double quotes (" ") as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859101/what-does-ahref-do-in-css

Comment: I have added the quotes. While it may work without using quotes the CSS specs do require them for strings. Thanks Panagiotis.

Comment: Thanks! This has been driving me crazy. Best answer for retaining the functionality too (and should probably be the recognised answer!)

Answer (score 31):

If you want to retain the *function* of the phone-number, but just remove the underline for display purposes, you can style the link as any other:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none; /* or: underline | line-through | overline | blink (don't use blink. Ever. Please.) */ }
```

I haven't seen documentation that suggest a class is applied to the phone number links, so you'll have to add classes/ids to links you *want* to have a different style.

Alternatively you can style the link using:

```
a[href^=tel] { /* css */ }
```

Which is understood by iPhone, and won't be applied (so far as I know, perhaps Android, Blackberry, etc. users/devs can comment) by any other UA.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use `a[href^=tel:]` so that you don't accidently match hrefs to `telephone.html` etc.

Comment: @MattiasWadman your suggestion did not work for me in Chrome or mobile Safari.

Answer (score 15):

In case people find this question on Google, all you need to do is treat the telephone number as a link as Apple will automatically set it as one.

your HTML

```
<p id="phone-text">Call us on <strong>+44 (0)20 7194 8000</strong></p>
```

your css

```
#phone-text a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, all the top comments fail to mention this explicitly.

Answer (score 13):

Since we use tel: links on a site with a phone-icon on :before most solutions posted here introduces another problem.

I used the meta-tag:

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`

This combined with specifying *tel: links* site-wide where it should be linked!

Using css is really not an option as it hides relevant tel-links.

Comment: Thank you for this! Works perfect on Cordova/Ionic.

Answer (score 7):

```
a[href^=tel]{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-style:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
```

Answer (score 6):

An old question but as none of the above answers were good for me i post how i resolved it

I have a phone number in a list:

```
<li class="phone_menu">+555 5 555 55 55</li>
```

css:

```
.phone_menu{
  color:orange;
}
```

But on iPad/iPhone it was black, so i just added this to the css:

```
.phone_menu a{
  color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple trick worked for me, adding a hidden object in the middle of phone number.

```
<span style="color: #fff;">
0800<i style="display:none;">-</i> 9996369</span>
```

This will help you to override phone number color for IOS.

Comment: It works, but breaks link functionality. For needing things in a pinch (like today) it's fine.

Comment: Your example did not work for me, but zero-width joiner &zwj; did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve been going back and forth between

1.

```
    <a href="tel:5551231234">
```

2.

```
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Trying to make the same code work for desktop and iPhone. The problem was that if the first option is used and you click it from a desktop browser it gives an error message, and if the second one is used it disables the tab-to-call functionality on iPhone iOS5.

So I tried and tried and it turned out that iPhone treats the phone number as a special type of link that can be formatted with CSS as one. I wrapped the number in an address tag (it would work with any other HTML tag, just try avoiding `<a>` tag) and styled it in CSS as

```
.myDiv address a {color:#FFF; font-style: normal; text-decoration:none;}
```

and it worked  - in a desktop browser showed a plain text and in a Safari mobile showed as a link with the Call/Cancel window popping up on tab and without the default blue color and underlining.

**Just be careful with the css rules applied to the number especially when using padding/margin.**

Answer (score 2):

No need to remove format detection by using `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`. Try using phone number in any tag rather then anchor tag and style it accordingly e.g.: `span { background:none !important; border:0; padding:0; }`

Answer (score 1):

[`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#format-detection).  This metatag works in the default Safari browser on iOS devices and will only work for telephone numbers that are not wrapped in a telephone link so

```
1-800-123-4567
<a href="tel:18001234567">1-800-123-4567</a>
```

the first line will not be formatted as a link if you specify the metatag but the second line will because it's wrapped in a telephone anchor.

---

You can forego the metatag all-together and use a mixin such as

```
a[href^=tel]{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-style:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
}
```

to maintain intended styling of your telephone numbers, but you must make sure you wrap them in a telephone anchor.

If you want to be extra cautious and protect against the event of a telephone number which is not properly formatted with a wrapping anchor tag you can drill through the DOM and adjust with this script.  Adjust the replacement pattern as desired.

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})/g, '<a href="tel:+1$1$2$3">($1) $2-$3</a>'));
```

or even better without jQuery

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})/g,'<a href="tel:+1$1$2$3">($1) $2-$3</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to have any telephone numbers on your page, then
    `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">`
will work just fine. But rhetorically speaking, what if you intend to use a mix of phone and non-phone numbers?

Assuming you're just hard-coding numbers into your HTML, the "insert stuff in the middle of your digits" hacks will work. But they are of little to no use for dynamic pages, such as using PHP to output numerical data from a query.

As an example, I was generating a list of city populations. Some of the populations were large enough to cause Mobile Safari to turn them into phone number links. Fortunately, all I had to do was use PHP `number_format()` around the array output to insert "thousands" commas:

`<?php echo number_format($row["population"]) ?>`

This formatting was enough to convince Mobile Safari that there was a somewhat more specific purpose for the number, so it didn't default my larger numbers into telephone links anymore. The same would hold true for the suggestion by @davidcondrey of using `<a href="tel:18001234567">1-800-123-4567</a>` to specify a purpose to the number.

Bottom line is that Safari Mobile apparently does pay attention to semantics. Given that HTML5 is built around semantic markup, and search engines are relying on semantic markup, I intend to use it as much as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the number in a <fieldset> will prevent iOS from converting the number to a link for some reason. In some cases this could be the right solution. I don't advocate a blanket disabling of converting to links.

Answer (score 1):

iOS makes phone numbers clickable by defaults (for obvious reasons). Of course, that adds an extra tag which is overriding your styling if your phone number isn’t already a link.

To fix it, try adding this to your stylesheet: `a[href^=tel] { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }`

That should keep your phone numbers styled as you expect without adding extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
.appleLinks a {color:#000000;}
.appleLinksWhite a {color:#ffffff;}
```

You can find more info [here](http://litmus.com/blog/remove-blue-links-ios).

Answer (score 0):

Try using putting the ASCII character for the dash in between the digit separations.

from this: -

to this: `&ndash;`

ex: change `555-555-5555` => `555&ndash;555&ndash;5555`

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla Yootheme works for me:

```
a:not([class]) {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This x-ms-format-detection="none" attribute handle the format phone.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337007(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<p id="phone-text" x-ms-format-detection="none"  >Call us on <strong>+44 (0)20 7194 8000</strong></p>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you simply want to avoid phone numbers being links at all try using the font tag:

```
<p>800<font>-</font>555<font>-<font>1212</p>
```