# What does a[href^="..."] do in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have used CSS before and I came across the below CSS style, don't have a clue what it does.

```css
a[href^="http:"] {
   background: url(img/keys.gif) no-repeat right top;
}
a[href^="http://mysite.com"], a[href^="http://www.mysite.com"] {
   background-image: none; padding-right:0;
}
```

Comment: Must know info here: http://edgar.tumblr.com/post/1483797785/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-know-memorize

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
a[href^="http:"]
```

Selects an `<a>` element whose `href` attribute value begins with `http:`.

**For example:**

```css
p[title^="para"] {background: green;}
```

Will match the following:

```html
<p title="paragraph"> This paragraph should have a green background. </p>
```

Answer (score 36):

That's one of the [substring-matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) available in CSS3. It matches links with `href` attributes whose values start with the given string.

To illustrate, we'll take your example CSS, and add some defaults:

```css
a {
   background: none; padding: 0 1em;
}

a[href^="http:"] {
   background: url(img/keys.gif) no-repeat right top;
}

a[href^="http://mysite.com"], a[href^="http://www.mysite.com"] {
   background-image: none; padding-right:0;
}
```

And style the following HTML with it. The output styles are summarized in comments:

```html
<ul>
    <!-- [1] No background, 1em left and right padding -->
    <li><a href="/index.php">My site's page</a></li>

    <!-- [2] Background, 1em left and right padding -->
    <li><a href="http://example.com">External link</a></li>

    <!-- [3] No background, no right padding -->
    <li><a href="http://mysite.com">My site's base URL without www</a></li>        

    <!-- [4] No background, no right padding -->
    <li><a href="http://www.mysite.com">My site's base URL with www</a></li>

    <!-- [5] No background, no right padding -->
    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page.php">A page in my site with base URL</a></li>
</ul>
```

What's happening?

1. **Selected by `a` only**
   This element's `href="/index.php"` attribute doesn't start with `http:` or the other values.

   There is no background, but there is left and right padding.
2. **Selected by `a[href^="http:"]` only**
   This element's `href="http://example.com"` attribute starts with `http:` but doesn't start with `http://mysite.com`.

   There is both left and right padding, and a background image.
3. **Selected by `a[href^="http:"]` and `a[href^="http://mysite.com"]`**
   This element's `href="http://mysite.com"` attribute starts with `http:` and further starts with `http://mysite.com`.

   Since the second selector overrules the first selector, the background image and right padding are removed.
4. **Selected by `a[href^="http:"]` and `a[href^="http://www.mysite.com"]`**
   This element's `href="http://www.mysite.com"` attribute starts with `http:` and further starts with `http://www.mysite.com` (notice the www).

   Since the second selector overrules the first selector, the background image and right padding are removed.
5. **Selected by `a[href^="http:"]` and `a[href^="http://mysite.com"]`**
   This element's `href="http://mysite.com/page.php"` attribute starts with `http:` and further starts with `http://mysite.com`.

   Notice that, compared to the third link, the attribute in this one contains more than just the base URL; however, the `^=` indicates that the attribute's value just needs to *start with* your site's base URL, as opposed to `=` which would mean "select links that only point to `http://mysite.com`". Therefore, this link is matched by the second selector.

   Since the second selector overrules the first selector, the background image and right padding are removed.

Answer (score 7):

Those are [attribute-starts-with selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), they'll select `<a>` elements with an `href` attribute starting with that value, e.g. `a[href^="http:"]` matches any anchors with an `href` starting with `href="http:...."`, for example:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com">Test</a> <!-- would match -->
<a href="#element">Test</a>              <!-- wouldn't match -->
```

Comment: so do you mean if there is a css selector say with 
a[href^=”http://www.google.com”] {
   color: red;}
only the a anchor link which has href="www.google.com" will be in red?

Comment: @user443946 - nope, but if both had the `www.` then it would be red, it has to start with *exactly* the same string.  Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7hnAB/ (make sure you're in a newer browser that supports the selectors).

Comment: Is that using this regular expression? [^ ] (quote from wikipedia follows) Matches a single character that is not contained within the brackets. For example, [^abc] matches any character other than "a", "b", or "c". [^a-z] matches any single character that is not a lowercase letter from "a" to "z". As above, literal characters and ranges can be mixed.

Comment: @orolo - It's not a regex, there are only specific cases that work, here's a table of them: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: @user443946: That would only match if the tag was `<a href="google.com/somethind" ...`. The selector doesn't check for semantic, it just compares what's inside of the attribute, and if the value starts with the same text as in your selector, it matches.

Answer (score 5):

For every link which's "href" parameter starts with "http:", set the background to a key image (without repetition, positioned in the top-right corner).

For every link which's "href" parameter starts with "http://mysite.com" or "http://www.mysite.com", set the background image to nothing (and the right-side padding to 0).

To me, this seems like a clever CSS trick that will make your users aware of when they are leaving your website through an external link by displaying a key image.

(I think I'll use it in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

The rules say, according to [the W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

- All anchors which have an `href` attribute that starts with `http:`
- All anchors which have an `href` attribute that start with `http://mysite.com` or `http://www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

It's an attribute selector.
The **^=** part means that the href attribute of the anchor tags must **begin** with `http:` in your first example.