# Link font in markdown

Tags: html, url, markdown

I'm trying to have a link with large font to a different page.

Doing it this way causes it to link to the same page (url is same_page+"#"):

```
<h1><a href="foo.html">Let's go to different Page!</a></h1>
```

Is it possible to have a link in markdown of roughly equal font size to h1 text without resorting to html?

This way has the link working and the font almost same as h1, but I'd prefer a strictly native markdown solution:

```
<a href="foo.html"><font size="6"><b>Let's go to different Page!</b></font></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The size attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_size.asp)

The next problem is: in native markdown you cant use css classes. In markdown-extra and some other implementation you can set [special attributes](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr) like:

```
[link](url){#id .class}
```

If you have none of this, you can use [Substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) as workaround. A [example how that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859101/what-does-ahref-do-in-css).