# CSS Output in Firefox and Chrome explained? [id^="exlidInput_scope"]

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Google Chromes developer tools and Firebug both display the CSS on one of the ID's that I'm trying to manipulate as follows:

```
[id^="exlidInput_scope"]
```

The line of code is as follows:

```
<select name="vl(3UI0)" id="exlidInput_scope_1" class="EXLSelectTag blue     EXLSimpleSearchSelect" style="margin-top: -22px; border: 1px solid purple;">...</select>
```

I want to manipulate it in jquery doing something like this:

```
$("[id^="exlidInput_scope"]").css({ 'margin-left': '5px !important'});
```

However I don't really understand the markup that's being used. So the id obviously refers to the fact that its an id however what is this part for? Do I need to reference it like that, or is that something that the browser does just to output it to me?

```
^=
```

Any help appreciated - I'm new to CSS and not understanding this is a real pain!

Comment: you probably need to escape the double quotes:
`$("[id^='exlidInput_scope']")`

Comment: change quotes to simple quote `$("[id^='exlidInput_scope']").css({ 'margin-left': '5px !important'});`

Comment: This worked, if one of you puts this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one! Still unsure what the ^= signifies though?

Comment: Surprised no one answered it. It means "select elements whose id *starts with* `exlidInput_scope`" You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859101/what-does-ahref-do-in-css/3859189#3859189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change double quotes to simple quote like so: `$("[id^='exlidInput_scope']").css({ 'margin-left': '5px !important'});`