# hyperlink an image via CSS without JS, Action, Object etc

Tags: html, css, href

Hoping someone cal help me with this issue i am having.

I need to hyperlink an image which will be as a background image in CSS. Is there a way to do this?

Unfortunately I cant use jQuery, JS, Ajax, Object or any form of actions. Scripts are 100% blocked.

I have access to HTML however for this particular image I need it to come from within the CSS and to be hyperlinked.

Is there anyway to do this?

thanks

Danny

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background image using CSS:

```
body {
   background-image: url("paper.gif");
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

But, if you need it to also be hyperlinked (eg, you need to be able to click on it, then technically, it is no longer a background image. For that, you could try something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859101/what-does-ahref-do-in-css) and then set the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to something like -1.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to hyperlink an image which will be as a background image in
>   CSS. Is there a way to do this?

No you cant link an element in CSS.

You can create an a tag and give it a class

HTML -

```
<a href="/link" class="background-image"></a>
```

CSS -

```
.background-image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('location/of/your/img.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with a link or by wraping a element with the background in a link

```
<a href="link.html"></a>


a {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100vw;//change
   height: 100vh;//change
   background-image: url("paper.gif");
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

or a [input type image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) in a form

```
 <input type="image" src="/files/2917/fxlogo.png" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the reply.

I may try just wrapping an empty div with a href as mention above and minify the html.

the main issue i am having is that i want to place a signature and don't want it to be easly disabled with either adding display:none or removing directly from the html.

My current method i am using jQuery and adding it after a specific DIV so the user can not disable as they dont have access to some of the core files.

I'll play around, some great ideas here so thanks again for the quick reply :)

Answer (score -1):

Via CSS it's impossible. That's not what the language is  made to do.Your best shot to bypass js scripts is to focus on HTML5 attributes.