# How to use css selector nth-of-type and nth-child to locate element in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

Below is a snippet of how a page is set up.

```
<class id="class1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>section 1</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home1">some link 1</a>
    <li>
      <strong>section 2</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home">some link 2</a>
<class id="class1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>section 3</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home/abc">some link 3</a>
    <li>
      <strong>section 4</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home/def">some link 4</a>
```

how do i locate link.com/home in section 2?

I figured this would work:

```
.class1:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-child(2) [href*="/home"]
```

But it doesn't. It finds the link in section 4 as well. I have to use *= because in different environments the url prefix changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I have added the *`</li>`*, *`</ul>`* and *`</class>`* tags at the appropriate places and the ideal HTML will be:

```
<class id="class1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>section 1</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home1">some link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>section 2</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home">some link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</class>
<class id="class1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <strong>section 3</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home/abc">some link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <strong>section 4</strong>
      <a href="link.com/home/def">some link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</class>
```

To locate the *`href`* attribute of *section 2* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `nth-child()`:

  ```
  class#class1 > ul li:nth-child(2) a[href$="home"]
  ```
- Using `nth-child()`:

  ```
  class#class1 > ul li:nth-of-type(2) a[href$="home"]
  ```

---

### Solution

To print the value of the *href* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using `nth-child()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "class#class1 > ul li:nth-child(2) a[href$='home']").get_attribute("href"))
  ```
- Using `nth-child()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "class#class1 > ul li:nth-of-type(2) a[href$='home']").get_attribute("href"))
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[What is the difference between p:nth-child(2) and p:nth-of-type(2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493178/what-is-the-difference-between-pnth-child2-and-pnth-of-type2)

Comment: hi, thank you, that worked.  can i ask you another question?  what if both URLs were exactly the same but I wanted the one only from section 2.  is that possible?

Comment: Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?