# Prevent iPhone from highlighting phone numbers on webpage

Tags: iphone, html, ios, mobile-safari

Do you know if there is a specific meta tag (like for the Skype toolbar) that I can add to my web page so that all iOS devices do not turn phone numbers (and sometimes dates, too) into clickable links?

Comment: See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/keep-iphone-browser-from-turning-numbers-into-links

Comment: Thanks! Maybe we should close this question then, since I can't mark your comment as answer ;)

Comment: There's no blame in answering your own question and marking it as the correct one.

Comment: Should have been closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers instead.