# Hidden Field converted to phone number link on iPad and iPhone

Tags: html, ios, mobile, hyperlink, hidden-field

I have a hidden field on my page that has a number in it and ipad/iphone tries to make it into a phone number link - making me unable to submit the form (potentially dangerous). If it is a hidden field why is it even doing this? and anyone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

From the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3736807/3009), you can remove all auto-formatting for telephone numbers by adding this to the head of your html document.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```