# numeric content being stripped out/hidden on tablet/mobile devices

Tags: iphone, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a broblem with [this site](http://www.ayrshirebakerybox.co.uk) where, on an iPad 3 and iPhone 4, I am finding the the mobile number is being removed/hidden when the element only contains a numerical value. When I prepend the value with "mob-" it works.

```
<span class="r" style="width: 100%">mob-0123456789</span>
```

So, when I have it like this below it doesn't show:

```
<span class="r" style="width: 100%">0123456789</span>
```

I have raked through my `@media` queries, but I can't find anywhere that is preventing it from displaying. The site is responsive so there are a number of `@media` queries for different screen sizes. It displays differently on an iPhone as it does on an iPad, but the hidden numeric content is the same on both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers - might be worth a look

Comment: Strip out all styles...if you still can't see the value, @RayAlex is probably on the right track.

Comment: @RayAlex Spot on, Ray. I added `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` to my meta tags and this resolved the problem. Check the link above on an iPhone. Do you want to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to [How do I remove the blue styling of telephone numbers on iPhone/iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers)

If you add the following to the meta tags, this should resolve the issue.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```