# IOS Safari Displaying Text Colour Differently

Tags: html, ios, css

This is driving me mad why is the contact number at the top and bottom of this site being displayed correctly as red in all browsers, but in IOS safari the top number is grey and the bottom number is white?

http://dpacinstallations.co.uk/

Please help i am going a little loopy trying to figure this out!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default iOS Safari behaviour on phone numbers.

Check out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).

**Also:**

[How to disable phone number linking in Mobile Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226131/how-to-disable-phone-number-linking-in-mobile-safari)

[remove styling of telephone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers)