# How to keep linked phone number from breaking line on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, css, hyperlink, line-breaks

I'm working on [a website](http://stage.custombuiltwindows.com) that is set up to be a responsive design that gracefully transforms according to the size of the screen it's viewed on.

With iOS, I'm noticing that whenever I display the business phone number in an excerpt that displays underneath a slideshow element, the anchor tag that iOS automatically inserted  causes a line break just before showing the phone number. [See this screenshot for detail](http://postimg.org/image/po39ytx59/).

Sorry, but I have NO *rendered* source code to show this as iOS doesn't expose that via any kind of "view source" feature. If there is a way to show my source as rendered on iOS, please let me know.

I do have the *pre-rendered* CSS that, based on screen size, triggers the right line spacing between the break and the text above it, but it has been difficult to find a balance between line spacing and positioning. Here is that code:

First, for "normal" screens:

```
.content .genesis_responsive_slider .slide-excerpt {
    background-color: #222;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    height: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 4%;
}
```

Next for "mobile" screens lte 480px wide:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

     .content #genesis-responsive-slider .slide-excerpt {
         font-size:inherit;
         height: 24%;
         padding:4% 0 0 0;
         line-height: .5rem;
     }

}
```

Is there a way to prevent that anchor text line break on small iOS screens?

Comment: You shouldn't need View Source, surely you can just capture this server-side or use another browser, right?  I mean, you liked to the site right there.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this same issue for a project I'm working on.  I found this answer that solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056764/1778696

All you do is add this in the head

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

and then add this to your phone numbers to keep them clickable as phone numbers

```
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```