# Iphone changes font color of phone numbers to back

Tags: html, iphone, css

Iphone changes font color of phone numbers to black on my website. I want it to be white. `color: #fff !important;` doesn't help. How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide more code / css to help you out. Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Comment: @kermit put your code here.

Comment: there is no need to put code here, question is simple:)

Comment: what website are we talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers

Answer (score 2):

iOS makes phone numbers clickable by defaults (for obvious reasons). Of course, that adds an extra tag which is overriding your styling if your phone number isn’t already a link.

To fix it, try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
a[href^=tel] { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
```

That should keep your phone numbers styled as you expect without adding extra markup.

Hope it helps!