# Remove blue hyperlink for phone number in email

Tags: html, html-email

Similar to this question, [How do I remove the blue styling of telephone numbers on iPhone/iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios/11092531#11092531?newreg=e98f4afc01944f69bfe40f72c26c53b3)

I tried the suggestion using following code but it does not work:

```
[href^="tel"]{
    color:inherit;
}
```

My problem is I am copying a page from my website into an email (weekly newsletter), and gmail is converting it to a blue hyperlink. Even before adding a[href^="tel"], it did not show up as blue on my website. I'm thinking there is no fix since it is happening via google?

Comment: Use  this css
a {
text-decoration: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

if this is happening on gmail app, you can use an anchor tag and give it a color *without* the href

```
<a style="color:#000001; text-decoration:none;">iOS Fix</a>
```

if this is happening on the generic email clients for iOS you can use a class in the header and assign the class to the td

```
<style>
.appleLinkFix a{color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
</style>
```

next you can add the class to the td which iOS will create the link by itself.

```
<td class="appleLinkFix">48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009</td>
```

Hope that helps answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add these styles

```
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
```

This is also very easy to Google.