# Why is the font color of a phone number blue on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts, html-email

Does anyone know why the font color on **iPad iOS 11.0, iPhone 7 iOS 11.0, iPhone X iOS 11.0.3** is blue? I tried to change the color in many ways but not working at all, I don't even have any blue color in my email code so it must be computed!

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" style="background: #333d47; text-align: left; color: #FFFFFF;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px; color: #FFFFFF; margin:0; padding:20px; font-weight: 300 !important;">Contact us now: <span editable="true" style="color: #FFFFFF;">+1(555) 555-555</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: these agents detect phone number pattern and allow to call to it by clicking, you can try to set color of `A` tag

Comment: you mean wrap the phone with `<a>` instead of span ? @IlyaBursov

Comment: no, just define color for A tag

Comment: I do have a tag color set to white. I tried to change the color of everything wrapping this content but color wont change!

Comment: how did you set color for `A`?

Comment: `a { color: #FFFFFF; }` and `a { color: white;}` and I added `!important`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167848/discussion-between-adam-and-ilya-bursov).

Comment: Just a little search would have done it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43303450/remove-blue-hyperlink-for-phone-number-in-email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blue hyperlink for phone number in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43303450/remove-blue-hyperlink-for-phone-number-in-email)

Comment: @Syfer this is not anchor tag. read the question, and my answer at the bottom said this works with `<a>` but not `<span>`

Comment: It's an alternative to use span so the underline and color change are not affected on visited ok different devices. As for the `a` not being an anchor I think the web itself disagrees with you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167907/discussion-between-adam-and-syfer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS solved the problem in most clients

```
*[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
    .x-gmail-data-detectors,    /* Gmail */
    .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
    .aBn {
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
        cursor: default !important;
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
    }
```

Comment: A+. The answer I gave above comes from the same place (https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/) but pared down for just iOS (your question), but this answer covers Gmail too.

Answer (score 3):

iOS gives us `x-apple-data-detectors` to work around Apple Mail meddling with auto-detecting phone numbers and addresses and making them links. Placing something like this in your `<style>` tag should do the trick:

```
*[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
    cursor: default !important;
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS renders strings that it interprets as phone numbers as clickable links by default.

Use the `format-detection` meta tag and you can disable this feature:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

See: [Supported Meta Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

Comment: If putting that meta tag in the `<head>` of your email didn't work, you could also try placing a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of the email and targeting `a[href^=tel]` with CSS.  [This blog post](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices) actually has several other options, including the two I've mentioned here.

Comment: but this is not an anchor tag! its `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to just define `color in span tag` like given below

```css
 a { color: #FFFFFF !important; }
  span { color: #FFFFFF !important; }
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" style="background: #333d47; text-align: left; color: #FFFFFF;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px; color: #FFFFFF; margin:0; padding:20px; font-weight: 300 !important;">Contact us now: <span editable="true" style="color: #FFFFFF;">+1(555) 555-555</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add this to your site header

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

This happens as iOS detects phone numbers and turns them into links that people can click to call them. You can turn off the behavior by adding this in your  section.

Comment: adding this by itself won't solve the problem, but adding `*[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
    .x-gmail-data-detectors,    /* Gmail */
    .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
    .aBn {
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
        cursor: default !important;
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
    }` in the head will make it work. try it out