# Safari - how to disable automatically underlined links which cause problems on black background?

Tags: css, safari, background, underline

I have the following problem: The background of my page is black. 
In white letters I have the telephone number. In my Iphone (safari browser) the link gets black and therefore it can not be seen. With all other browser I don't have the same problem...
The code I use:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;text-decoration:none;">Tel. : 0171 268 5450</span></p>
```

I think that Safari recognizes the field as telephone number and underlines it. How to get rid of it?

Comment: So, after some searching I found the answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove the blue styling of telephone numbers on iPhone/iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible it is a previously visited link? some browsers will have different font colors for links depending on if the user has visited them or not.

```
a:visited { color: white !important; }
```

Comment: That was not the problem, but I found another solution which is shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios

Comment: You should edit the above post to show people it is [solved] since there is no accepted answer.