# Safari not working with bootstrap nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a nav top bar in bootstrap. Every browser it is working fine, but on Safari it messes up the phone number and email. Does anyone know why?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #003366">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left: 20px;">
          <font color="white"><h3><i>Company</i></h3></font>
          <font color="white" size="1">
            123 Main Ave<br />
            Managers Office Suite 100 - Manager Name<br />
            xxx.xxx.xxxx<br />
            email@propertyemail.com
          </font>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p style="margin-right: 50px;" align="right">

          <font color="white" size="5"><i>11:40, AM<br />Tuesday, June 12, 2018</i></font>

        </p>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: FWIW: Safari must be version 9 or higher

Comment: though that doesn't explain why emails or phone numbers would be affected

Comment: I'm testing on my iPhone 7, so I believe it has Safari higher than 9.

Comment: based on your html above you are doing some pretty basic stuff, when I created a snippet here it's fine so that's leading me to believe that Safari on iPhone 7 is being clever and picking up recognized text and applying it's own formatting that may be breaking Bootstrap

Comment: [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/how-do-i-remove-the-blue-styling-of-telephone-numbers-on-iphone-ios)