# Keep phone numbers from being converted to links on Opera Mobile

Tags: html, mobile, opera

Apparently, those guys at Opera have added a nice feature to their mobile version of the browser: They convert things looking like phone numbers into HTML links on webpages (e.g. USD 15.50, which clearly isn't a phone number).

The feature is described here: http://my.opera.com/operamobile/blog/2010/02/12/opera-mobile-10-beta-3-for-both-symbian-s60-and-windows-mobile

Can that be suppressed in HTML using a proprietary META tag or something like that? It really screws up our application... Do other mobile browsers also have such a feature that I should be aware of?

**EDIT**: Thanks for providing me with the link to the questions indicating the `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` tag. That appears to solve the problem on the iPhone, but not on Opera Mobile

Comment: I am pretty sure iPhone does this also.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712475/mobile-html-rendering-numbers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers

Comment: @patrickmdnet that is an answer not a comment :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that meta tag doesn't seem to work for Opera Mobile :-/

Comment: try this one, helped me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lame solution:

Use Javascript to remove any links with href="tel:...".

Comment: That lame solution is just good enough. Although, it really is lame :)

Comment: This does not work with Opera Mobile 12, there are no `<a href="tel:">` elements surrounding the hyperlinked phone number.

Comment: Well, I did say it was lame. :-/ *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error this seems to work in Opera Mobile and on Mobilizer:

The HTML text (really should be "Samsung MSC 13800 TEU")

Samsung MSC 13,800 TEU

(put a span tag around the comma with a class of "hide")

The CSS

span.hide {
  display:none;
}

The comma is a fudge within "13800 TEU" and probably very annoying for assistive technology users (those with screen readers) but I follow that 80-20 principle (there would be more confused sighted users than those with a vision impairment ;-)