# Mobile browsers incorrectly rendering numbers as telephones

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have a form with a bunch of plain numbers and telephone.

Like this person, [Mobile HTML rendering numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712475/mobile-html-rendering-numbers)
some of the numbers get rendered as telephones.

Is there a way to prevent the number fields being clickable and rendered as telephones? I already have a tel: link in the telephone . I don't want to use the meta tag to disable all rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the format-detection meta tag in your header section:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Also you can use "span" in between the numbers (not recommended. coding nightmare):

```
<span>718</span><span>265</span><span>342</span>
```

Then use for iPhone and Android:

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the metatag to disable format detection for telephone numbers only, then explicitly enable the "tel:" link in the href attribute.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

...

```
<a href="tel:5555555555">555-555-5555</a>
```